# TypeError: 'Scene' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I'm trying to search for all items in bpy.context.scene that have same name, but different suffix number (bpy.context.scene["list_1"], .["list_2"] etc. 
It works if I search for objects under bpy.context.scene.objects:

```
for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if "list" in ob.name:
        print("woohoo!")
```

But as for items that are stored under scene, I get this error: "TypeError: 'Scene' object is not iterable" 

How can I search through these items and remove them from scene with a script? Some have used len() and range() with good result, but I haven't managed to make it work?


Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for [ID properties](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc%3A2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Properties) of the scene objects ie `scene[idprop]`

The list of all custom properties names of the scene will be in  `scene.keys()`

The `keys()` method of a blender object returns a list of all custom property names.

```
for key in scene.keys():
    if key.startswith("list"):
        print("scene['%s'] = " % key, scene[key].to_list())
```

Similarly the `items()` method returns a list of key value pairs

```
for key, val in scene.items():
    if key.startswith("list"):
        print("scene['%s'] = " % key, val.to_list())
```

also lets say we want "list_2" but don't know if it exists, if it doesn't `scne["list_2"]` will throw a key error, in this case recommend using get

```
list2 = scene.get("list_2")
if list2 is not None:
    print(list2.to_list())
else:
    print("no list named list_2 in scene")
```

or `list2_exists =  "list_2" in scene.keys()` could be used.

Comment: for ob in scene.keys():
    if ob.startswith("selSet"):
        bpy.ops.wm.properties_remove(data_path="scene", property=ob)